# The read() method, etc., of SYS.STDIN - where to get more info?

Tags: python

Where (url?) at [Python.org](https://www.python.org) can I find the *method or methods* (like read()) that are associated with sys.stdin? In the documenation at [Python.org](https://www.python.org), I found information for stdin in the library `sys`, but nothing about methods like `sys.stdin.read()` associated with `sys.stdin`?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a io.`TextIOWrapper`, with `read` inherited from `TextIOBase`.  Is there something special that you need to know?  In many ways it's just another file opened in test read mode.

Comment: @hpaulj I would not had known that ("It's a io.TextIOWrapper, with read inherited from TextIOBase") since the documentation does not explicitly say that. Seems to be one would have to read between the lines.

I searched and found an article about how to enter multiple lines of text (pasting or simply typing text per line)at the console and suggested to use sys.stdin.read() . I want to know more about read(), hence the inquiry.

Comment: `print(sys.stdin)` shows `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`.  Of `type(sys.stdin)` for a shorter description.  The rest comes from looking up `TextIOWrapper` in the Python docs.  In general identifying the type (or class) of an an object is the start of learning about its methods.

Comment: In an `Ipython` session I can do `sys.stdin.read??` to see the help for this method.  It's builtin so no further code is shown.  The Ipython help/introspection tools are quite handy, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jupyter/ipython_dynamic_object_introspection.htm

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation of sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20stdin#sys.stdin) :

> These streams are regular text files like those returned by the open() function.

I think you're looking for the docs of [open](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open) and the docs of the [`io` objects](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.IOBase). The class `io.IOBase` and its subclasses (`TextIOWrapper`) that implement those methods are lilely those you are interested in.